# splitting a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a PHP array as follow :

```
$array = array("one" => "is one" , "two" => "is two" , "three" => "is three", "four" => "is four" , "five" => "is five" , "six" => "is six" , "seven" => "is seven" , "eight" => "is eight" , "nine" => "is nine" , "ten" => "is ten");
```

After partitioning this array into two groups that is 5 elements, using following method:

```
 function partition(Array $list, $p) {
    $listlen = count($list);
    $partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
    $partrem = $listlen % $p;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for($px = 0; $px < $p; $px ++) {
        $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    return $partition;
}
$partitioned = partition($array , 2);
```

Now to use this partitioned array i use the following code :

```
$totalArrays = count($partitioned);
for($pb=0; $pb < $totalArrays; $pb++){
    print_r($partitioned[$pb]);

}
```

The above `print_r($partitioned[$pb]);` outputs 2 arrays.

This displays the contents of both arrays as keys and values, what i actually wanted to achieve is that , i would like to save elements of first array into one file named "First.txt" and "Second.txt" for the second, the names doesn't matters they can be numbered but what matters is the partitions, forexample if there are 10 partitions each partition will save its element into its own file.

I have had some solutions but they ain't working as expected so i am here to request for your solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Discover [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$result = array_chunk($source, 5);
```

if you want to preserve keys, then specify third parameter:

```
$result = array_chunk($source, 5, true);
```

*Edit* since you need guide about writing this to files, I'll provide a hint:

```
$files = ['One.txt', 'Two.txt', 'Three.txt']; //fill this as you need
foreach(array_chunk($source, 5, true) as $i=>$partition)
{
   //write i-th partition to file with i-th name
   writePartition($files[$i], $partition);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seems to reserve keys as requested. something like "one : is one", "two : is two" and so forth.

Comment: Please, read not only my code, but also the link. This function _has third parameter_ which points to keys preserving

Comment: got it, i can see the preserve keys. Sorry about that.

Ok here is the thing :

This splits the array into 5 arrays, what i actually want is that suppose there are 30 items in an array, and i want 10 items per partition than each partition will save its content to a file, the saving process is easy but the main subject is that how to access each partition differently.. !

Comment: Are you joking on me? :p Use `foreach` for example

Comment: Using foreach in the for() loop didn't helped it, i don't think so i am getting it.. I'm definitely not joking , but i guess i m confused thats why i asked the question.

Comment: though that didn't worked out but thanks for the idea, i have used a small function to help it out, using your similar idea.. :) Thanks allot!